# jQuery - how can I find the element with a certain id?

Tags: jquery

I have a table and each of its `td` has a **unique id** that corresponds to some time intervals (`0800` til `0830`... `0830` til `0900` and so on).

I have an input text where the user will type the time intervals they want to block.

If they type an interval that doesn't exist in my table, in other words, if they type an interval that doesn't correspond to any of my `td's id's`, I want to show an alert saying something like `this interval is not available for blocking`.

But, I'm having difficulty to find this id.

I'm doing this:

```
    var horaInicial = $("#horaInicial").val().split(':')[0] + $("#horaInicial").val().split(':')[1]; // this is remover the ":" from a formatted hour

    var verificaHorario = $("#tbIntervalos").find("td").attr("id", horaInicial);
```

But this `verificaHorario` is actually setting all my td's to this horaInicial id.

How can I find the id in my table and if it doesn't exist show some alert?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you're trying to find an element by id, you don't need to search the table only - it should be unique on the page, and so you should be able to use:

```
var verificaHorario = $('#' + horaInicial);
```

If you need to search only in the table for whatever reason, you can use:

```
var verificaHorario = $("#tbIntervalos").find("td#" + horaInicial)
```

Comment: For me the way doesn't work, but working example: *$("#tbIntervalos").find("td#" + horaInicial)*

Comment: `$('#' + horaInicial);` will fail subtly if the ID contains a dot.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Dots can be escaped by backslash (e.g. `#some\.id`). https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Comment: @user1438038 – Of course they can, but a solution that requires manually identifying and escaping metacharacters in the selector is not a robust solution.  For one thing, that's not a CSS selector, but a jQuery one.  There are subtle differences and jQuery is far less precisely documented.  What actually are the metacharacters in a jQuery selector that have special meaning?  And is the answer guaranteed not to change in a future version?

Comment: @RichardSmith: There is no need to *manually identify metacharacters*. You can escape them with `replace()` and a simple regular expression. Though, I would recommend avoiding periods in IDs in the first place.

Answer (score 27):

I don't know if this solves your problem but instead of:

```
$("#tbIntervalos").find("td").attr("id", horaInicial);
```

you can just do:

```
$("#tbIntervalos td#" + horaInicial);
```

Answer (score 9):

This

```
var verificaHorario = $("#tbIntervalos").find("#" + horaInicial);
```

will find you the td that needs to be blocked.

Actually this will also do:

```
var verificaHorario = $("#" + horaInicial);
```

Testing for the size() of the wrapped set will answer your question regarding the existence of the id.

Answer (score 6):

This is one more option to find the element for above question

`$("#tbIntervalos").find('td[id="'+horaInicial+'"]')`

Answer (score 4):

As all html ids are unique in a valid html document why not search for the ID directly? If you're concerned if they type in an id that isn't a table then you can inspect the tag type that way?

Just an idea!

S