# Toggling between two buttons on a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, datatables, togglebutton

I am trying to toggle between two buttons on the same table. One of the buttons, when clicked takes away an input. The other adds the input back onto the table.

```js
function clogin() {
  $('vloginbtn').removeClass("selectedBtn");
  $('cloginbtn').addClass("selectedBtn");
  $('shortNameRow').show();
}

function vlogin() {
  $('cloginbtn').removeClass("selectedBtn");
  $('vloginbtn').addClass("selectedBtn");
  $('shortNameRow').hide();
}
```

```css
.selectedBtn {
  color : red; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="cloginbtn" type="button" 
     onclick="clogin()" class="switchBtn selectedBtn">CLIENT LOGIN</button>
  <button id="vloginbtn" type="button" 
     onclick="vlogin()" class="switchBtn">VENDOR LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `shortNameRow` element ?

Comment: jQuery [uses the `#` prefix](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for ID selectors. So, if you want to select the element whose ID is `id="cloginbtn"`, you have to use `$('#cloginbtn')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - how can I find the element with a certain id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638471/jquery-how-can-i-find-the-element-with-a-certain-id)

Answer (score 0):

You just had a few things to clean up as pointed out by the comments.

The input wasn't provided in the example code, so I added one.

You need to pass `#` to the selector in jQuery to select by `id`.

```js
const cLoginBtn = $("#cloginbtn");
const vLoginBtn = $("#vloginbtn");
const input = $("#shortNameRow");

cLoginBtn.click(function () {
  cLoginBtn.addClass("selectedBtn");
  vLoginBtn.removeClass("selectedBtn");
  input.show();
});

vLoginBtn.click(function () {
  vLoginBtn.addClass("selectedBtn");
  cLoginBtn.removeClass("selectedBtn");
  input.hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.selectedBtn {
  color: red;
}

.my-input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
        <button id="cloginbtn" type="button" class="switchBtn selectedBtn">
          CLIENT LOGIN
        </button>
        <button id="vloginbtn" type="button" class="switchBtn">
          VENDOR LOGIN
        </button>
        <div class="my-input">
          <input id="shortNameRow" />
        </div>
      </div>
```